# Cocoon Nested Resources Saving Belongs To Association Simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

I'm trying to create recipes in my app, and add ingredients dynamically with cocoon. Recipes and Ingredients both belong to Restaurant. Much like the examples, my params are passing correctly. However, I'm saving a recipe, thus the association with restaurant is set automatically. But, the association between ingredient and restaurant is not. In rails console, I can see all new ingredients being created but the restaurant_id column is not being populated. How would I force rails to also set that column?

### Params Passed:

```
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"...",
 "recipe"=>
  {"name"=>"Random Dish",
   "summary"=>"A random summary",
   "description"=>"A random description",
   "recipe_ingredients_attributes"=>
    {"1438959353582"=>{"ingredient_id"=>"2", "_destroy"=>"false"},
     "1438959355828"=>{"ingredient"=>{"name"=>"Chicken", "unit_of_measurement"=>"kg"}, "ingredient_id"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}},
 "commit"=>"Create Recipe",
 "controller"=>"recipes",
 "action"=>"create",
 "restaurant_id"=>"4"}
```

### Controller:

```
def create
    # require pry; binding.pry;
    @recipe = @restaurant.recipes.new(recipe_params)
    if @recipe.save
        flash[:success] = "Your recipe was created tastefully!"
        redirect_to restaurant_recipes_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end

def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(
        :name, :summary, :description,
        recipe_ingredients_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :ingredient_id,
        ingredient_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :name, :quantity]]
    )
end
```

### Views:

#### _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for([@restaurant, @recipe]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :summary %>
  <%= f.input :description, rows: 10%>
  <strong>Ingredients: </strong>
    <div id="recipe_ingredients">
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :recipe_ingredients do |recipe_ingredient| %>
        <%= render 'recipe_ingredient_fields', :f => recipe_ingredient %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Ingredient', f, :recipe_ingredients %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

#### _recipe_ingredient_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">  
    <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="recipe_from_list" style="display: inline;">
      <%= f.association :ingredient, collection: @restaurant.ingredients, prompt: 'Choose an existing ingredient', label: false %>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'or create a new ingredient', f, :ingredient, class: 'add-ingredient' %>
        <%= link_to_remove_association f, class: 'remove-tag btn btn-default btn-xs' do %>
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### _ingredient_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields form-inline">
  <%= f.input :name, :placeholder => 'ingredient name', :label => false %>
  <%= f.input :unit_of_measurement, collection: ['kg','grams','lb','oz', 'litres', 'ml'], :selected => '1' %>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean the `restaurant_id` column isn't being populated in the `ingredient` hash?

Comment: Yup, its not enforcing the association. Notice how I'm saving the restaurant.recipes object in the controller. That's why it makes sense that ingredient won't be associated to restaurant. I assume I'd have to do a lambda or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `restaurant_id` to the `_ingredient_fields.html.erb` and allow it in `recipe_params`

`_ingredient_fields.html.erb` :

```
= f.input :restaurant_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => @restaurant.id }
```

Given that the `Ingredient` model has a `restaurant_id` field

`Controller`

```
def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(
        :name, :summary, :description,
        recipe_ingredients_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :ingredient_id,
        ingredient_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :name, :quantity, :restaurant_id]]
    )
end
```

Comment: haha Awesome, I love it when the answer is as simple as this. Thank you :P